# Direct output from a command to a file including the original command, AND print in terminal

Tags: command-line

When running some tests, I need to run a series of commands. It would be extremely useful to me, and save me a lot of time, if there was a way to do all of these things:

- Run the command I need to run
- Redirect all the output from the command to a specified file
- Include the original command in the specified file
- Print the output from the original command in the terminal

People have suggested using tee to me which does a great job of printing to terminal as well as sending to a file but doesn't include the original command. What I'd like to end up with is a file where the first line is the command I ran, and then below that is the output from the command.

Someone suggested this:

```
echo "ls -l" | xargs -I{} bash -c "echo >> output.file; eval {} >> output.file"
```

But this doesn't either print the output in the terminal or include the original command in the file.

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Almost duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/688498/295286 .

Comment: I didn't find this in my search - not exactly the same, but would probably have led me to the answer.

Comment: yep, and this is why I said *almost* the duplicate. But to be perfectly honest with my opinion, you could take almost any solution from there, and make use of it with piping to `tee`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's `tee` you're searching for.

```bsh
ls -l | tee outfile
```

prints the output of `ls -l` to stdout (i.e. the terminal) and saves it in the file `outfile` at the same time. *But*: It doesn't write the command name neither to stdout nor to the file. To achieve that, just `echo` the command name before running the command and pipe both outputs to `tee`:

```bsh
( echo "ls -l" && ls -l ) | tee outfile
```

That's cumbersome to type, so why not define a function?

```bsh
both(){ ( echo "$@" && "$@" ) | tee outfile ;}
```

After that you can just run

```bsh
both ls -l
```

to get the desired result. Put the function in your `~/.bashrc` to have it defined in every new terminal.

If you want to be able to specify the output file as the first argument like in

```bsh
both output ls -l
```

instead make it:

```bsh
both(){ ( echo "${@:2}" && "${@:2}" ) | tee "$1" ;}
```

If you don't want the output file to be overwritten but rather append to it, add the `-a` option to `tee`.

Answer (score 9):

You could make use of the `script` command which will make a typescript file of everything printed to your terminal. It creates a forked shells and will record everything until that shell is exited.

```
$ script my_output
Script started on Tue 28 Nov 2017 09:46:15 AM UTC
$ whoami
ajefferiss
$ exit
Script done on Tue 28 Nov 2017 09:46:27 AM UTC
```

Then if I `cat my_output` I get the same output:

```
$ cat my_output
Script started on Tue 28 Nov 2017 09:46:15 AM UTC
$ whoami
ajefferiss
$ exit
exit

Script done on Tue 28 Nov 2017 09:46:27 AM UTC
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the debugging function of the shell together with `tee`:

```sh
( set -x; command1 args...; command2 args ) 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

- `( ... )` starts a sub-shell which allows you to “collect” the output streams of all commands executed within the sub-shell. It also contains the effect of the `set` command below to this sub-shell.
- `set -x` enables the `x` shell option which prints all commands that the shell runs to the standard error stream before running them.
- `2>&1` redirects stream 2 (standard error) to stream 1 (standard output).
- `|` redirects the the standard output stream of the left command to the standard input stream of the right command.
- `tee FILE` copies the standard input stream to the file `FILE` and to standard output.

If your command sequence is already in a script file it would make more sense to run it like this:

```sh
bash -x /path/to/script args... 2>&1 | tee output.log
```