# Is there any way to check history only of current session?

Tags: command-line, history

I wanted to know if there is any command or any other way I can check my command history only in the current session.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `history` built in `bash` allows specifying filenames when used with `-anrw` flags, and `-a` flag description from `help history` states:

> append history lines from **this session** to the history file

Therefore, we can do:

```
~$ history -a this_session.history
~$ cat ./this_session.history 
history mysession.history 
cat mysession.history 
clear
history -a this_session.history
```

For the record, `-w` (the write history to file opion) writes *whole* history to the specified file, so `-a` (append) here is preferred choice.

---

There's other manual ways. In particular `ksh` doesn't have `-a` flag as `bash` does, but what `ksh`  and `mksh` do have is `HISTFILE` environment variable ( and `bash` has that,too, because `bash` included lots of `ksh` features); by the way, this variable by default isn't set (at least `mksh` on Ubuntu didn't set it). So, for outputting current session to other file, we call `HISTFILE` prepended to command which in shell syntax means running command with additional environment variable you specify. Like so:

```
bash-4.4$ HISTFILE='mykshfile.hist' ksh
$ echo 'Hello'
Hello
$ echo 'World'
World
$ 
bash-4.4$ cat ./mykshfile.hist 
�echo 'Hello'
echo 'World'
```

What you also can see from this is that `ksh` and its related shells output history with special characters, instead of plain text as what `bash` does. So, you may want to open that file with `ksh`.

As far as the [POSIX  `/bin/sh`  shell on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), which is Debian Almquist Shell or Dash, there exists [`fc` built-in](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/fc.html). However, [on Ubuntu dash is compiled without lib-edit](https://askubuntu.com/q/1027012/295286), which is a conscious choice by Ubuntu developers for performance reasons, so `fc` and [other modes that require line editing](https://askubuntu.com/q/826754/295286)  don't work out of the box (unless recompile `dash` yourself and install `lib-edit`).

---

Shell neutral ways would be to [record your session with existing tools](https://askubuntu.com/q/161935/295286)   or [write your own function](https://askubuntu.com/q/688498/295286) to record on per-command basis.